# Parsing log containing JSON in Fluentd

Tags: ruby, kubernetes, fluentd

I'm using Fluentd to tail container logs in k8s. I'm using the `in_tail` input plugin to tail container logs, parsing using the `regexp` parse plugin to extract the relevant log. The log is a json that has to be extracted and sent to the output plugin. I'm doing the extraction using the `filter_parser` plugin using a `json` parser.

```
    <source>
      @type tail
      tag proxy.*
      ...
      read_from_head true
      <parse>
       @type regexp
       expression \[proxy\]\[(?<type>(record|replay))\](?<log>.*)
      </parse>
    </source>

    <filter proxy.**>
      @type parser
      key_name log
      <parse>
        @type json
      </parse>
    </filter>
```

Example log line:

```
[proxy][record]{"test":123}
```

This seems to produce a record as:

```
record={"type"=>"record", "log"=>"{\\\"test\\\":123}"}
```

When running the setup with the config, it looks like the value in the `log` regex group is being escaped (twice?); due to which the json parser in the filter section fails to parse it.

I suspect it has something to do with how the `regexp` plugin and/or the `in_tail` has been written. It might be picking that `log` value as a string and escaping it before passing it on.

Or is my regex missing something?

Does anyone know why this is happening and what the solution might be?

Comment: This issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/1278#issuecomment-508283873), it will release the fixed version in future.

Comment: @DaeinPark looks like that issue is for FluentBit and not Fluentd.

Comment: The output you have pasted is looks like internal record after `source` parsing using `regexp`, it still did not go through your `filter` yet. Once it goes through your `filter` above, it should parse the `log` field correct lyas json. I just tested above config with final `match` to `stdout` and it prints the json fine. What is your final `match` after the `filter` and why do you think it's failing?

Comment: Yes, it's the record after the `source` parsing. The filter seems to give an error `dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::Parser::ParserError error="pattern not match with data '{\\\"test\\\":123}\\n\",\"stream\":\"stderr\",\"time\":\"2019-08-27T11:14:15.23908372Z\"}'`". 
As for the `match` section, it is using `fluent-plugin-out-http` to make http calls. I don't think there's an issue with that.